# No such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/keycloak.json' when using keycloak-connect with meteorjs

Tags: meteor, keycloak, keycloak-connect

I have the following main.ts :

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import { TasksCollection } from '/imports/db/tasks';
import '/imports/api/tasksMethods';
import '/imports/api/tasksPublications';
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // create task
  //TasksCollection;
  // Meteor method to initiate authentication for realm1
  Meteor.methods({
    loginWithKeycloak: function () {
      const keycloakRealm1Config = {
        // Keycloak server URL
        authServerUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
        // Your Realm
        realm: 'test',
        // Client ID and Secret for your Meteor app
        resource: 'meteor',
        credentials: {
          secret: 'xR0GrapX6FlRSMN3YjrrfuX0OGdkRpVX',
        },
      }
      const keycloak = new Keycloak(keycloakRealm1Config);
      keycloak.init({
        onLoad: 'login-required',
      }).success((authenticated: any) => {
        if (authenticated) {
          // You can access user information via keycloak.idTokenParsed
          console.log(keycloak.idTokenParsed);
        }
      });
    },
  });
});
```

When i use Meteor.call("loginWithKeycloak") i get the following error :

```
I20230906-19:08:34.653(0)? hello
I20230906-19:08:52.723(0)? Exception while invoking method 'loginWithKeycloak' Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/keycloak.json'
I20230906-19:08:52.724(0)?     at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
I20230906-19:08:52.724(0)?     at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:394:35)
I20230906-19:08:52.725(0)?     at Config.loadConfiguration (/usr/src/app/node_modules/keycloak-connect/middleware/auth-utils/config.js:52:19)
I20230906-19:08:52.725(0)?     at new Config (/usr/src/app/node_modules/keycloak-connect/middleware/auth-utils/config.js:40:10)
I20230906-19:08:52.725(0)?     at new Keycloak (/usr/src/app/node_modules/keycloak-connect/keycloak.js:63:17)
I20230906-19:08:52.725(0)?     at MethodInvocation.loginWithKeycloak (imports/api/test.ts:17:26)
I20230906-19:08:52.726(0)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1902:12)
I20230906-19:08:52.726(0)?     at getCurrentMethodInvocationResult (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:772:38)
I20230906-19:08:52.726(0)?     at packages/meteor.js:365:18
I20230906-19:08:52.726(0)?     at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1389:31)
I20230906-19:08:52.726(0)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:791:46
I20230906-19:08:52.727(0)?     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
I20230906-19:08:52.727(0)?     at Session.method (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:739:23)
I20230906-19:08:52.727(0)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:603:43
```

I tried creating the file but even that didn't solve the issue. At this point any idea would help, does anyone know how to fix it ?